# Lite instead of Light

Tags: spelling, register

I commonly see *lite version*, *lite cream*, etc. When is it acceptable to replace *light* with *lite*?

Is *Lite* already accepted as correct English or is it just an informal/incorrect spelling? Are there any differences in meaning between the two, or is one just a more informal variant of the other?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Oxford English Dictionary has an entry for it:

> lite, adj.2 and n.6
>
> Comm. Designating a manufactured product that is lighter (in weight, calorie content, etc.) than the ordinary variety, esp. (with capital initial) low-calorie beer. Freq. used postpositively.
>
> 1962 L. S. Sasieni Princ. & Pract. Optical Dispensing i. 17   On light-weight spectacles a small joint known as the ‘Lite-Elete’ is sometimes used.

But beyond that definition it wouldn't be interchangeable with light.

For example, *the lite streamed in through the window*, would be incorrect usage.

Answer (score 7):

### Definitely Informal

*Lite* is a very incorrect and informal form of 'light', and it is used only in **advertisement** and **branding**.
Not sure about this, but it was most probably used by food companies first, 
saying that their product had less *fat* compared to other products.

Comment: In the UK at least, it is most commonly only seen in the context of advertising/branding, but it has crept into use in an (informal) idiomatic way when comparing two things---if Foo is some item/company/product and Bar is a very similar item/company/product with fewer features/properties then you could describe Bar as "Foo-Lite". Essentially, adding the suffix -lite implies that it has fewer features/properties.

Comment: Yes, that is true even in Apps. There is almost always an app with less features. If there is an app 'Booboo' (Totally random), then there will be an app 'Booboo-Lite'.