# Product Light or Lite?

Tags: synonyms

I need to publish new version of our product that has less capabilities. Shall we name it Product Light or Product Lite?

I read [Lite instead of Light](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/209/lite-instead-of-light) but I am not sure what to use. They said that Lite is incorrect but used in branding.

Comment: We don't recommend how to brand a product, this is a language site, you may ask about the difference in meaning and usage between the two terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on what your product is!

'Lite' is ***more common*** in the context of software tools. This 'lite' means it does not consume more memory or it occupies less space, and thus software runs faster. ['Lite' also mean that that software version has some limited functionalities or could support ads as well.](http://www.pcmag.com/encyclopedia/term/46182/lite-version)

On the other hand, if you have some other product (other than software), using 'light' is more common [as seen here.](http://www.optimavita.nl/wp-content/uploads/2014/10/lightproducten.jpg)